# Emacs in TTY + keyboard bindings

Tags: linux, emacs, terminal

I'm using emacs in TTY mode (`-nw`), and I can use most of the key bindings out of the box. However, there are key combinations I cannot find the xterm escape sequences for (like <kbd>C-;</kbd>, <kbd>C-<</kbd>, <kbd>C-></kbd>, etc.) I would like to configure my terminal emulator to send them, but can't find out where to start.

I also don't want to resort to defining custom escape sequences that I will later configure emacs to interpret via key remapping.

Any ideas/pointers I can use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First answer of this question will explain it: https://superuser.com/questions/83166/using-c-m-to-do-a-query-replace-regexp-in-emacs-running-in-mac-terminal

Basically there are just some key codes that cannot be sent to terminal applications.  I have noticed this behavior a number of times; <kbd>C-4</kbd> does not work the same way it does for me in the GUI version of Emacs.